# Can the ratio of the two smallest element of an iid sample converge to 1 if the support of $X$ is positive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, order-statistics, extreme-value-theorem

We have: $\mathbb P(X \leq 0)=0$ and $\mathbb P (X \leq a)>0$ for any $a>0$.

Comment: Doesn't something like the exponential of a standard Gaussian already provide a counter example? Then getting closer to zero gets exponentially less likely, so $X^{(2)}-X^{(1)}$ wil converge to zero but I don't think $X^{(2)}/X^{(1)}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if there exists a random variable with the given support such that the ratio still converges to 1 - I did not properly write that down; 1000x sorry

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Here is a counterexample. Lets $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ random samples from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.the order statistics $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ each have distribution 
\begin{align*} 
X_{(1)} &= \frac{Z_1}{\lambda n} \\ 
X_{(2)} &= \frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\frac{Z_1}{n}+\frac{Z_2}{n-1}\right)
\end{align*}
where the $Z_1, Z_2$ are iid standard exponential random variables (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#cite_note-4)).
Therefore 
$$
\frac{X_{(2)}}{X_{(1)}} = \frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2n/(n-1)} \rightarrow \frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2} \neq0
$$

Comment: I actually meant if it is possible to construct a random variable $X$ with the given support as indicated, such that the ratio will converge to 1; Sorry, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You're right for most cases, however this depends on the distribution as well.

If $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \Bbb{P}_\theta$ where $Var_\theta(X_i) = 0$, this doesn't hold true, because
$$\forall i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}\quad\Bbb{P}(X_i = X_j) = 1 \rightarrow \Bbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X_i}{X_j}=1\right)=1$$

But for most cases, where $Var_\theta(X_i) \ne 0$, you can prove this indirectly:

Let's assume that
$$\exists \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} := A \in \Bbb{R}^+_0 \cup \{+\infty\}$$
We can assume that $A \ge 0$, because $X^{(2)} \ge X^{(1)}$.

If

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} = A \stackrel{\text{then }}{\longrightarrow}\lim_{n \to \infty}\Bbb{E}\left(\frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(2)}}\right) = A$$

Since $\forall \varepsilon, N_1 \in \Bbb{R}^+ \exists, N_2 \in \Bbb{N}^+$ such that from a sample of $X_1,\dots,X_{N_1}$
$$A - \varepsilon < \frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} < A + \varepsilon,$$
We can assure that from a sample of $X_1,\dots,X_{N_2}$, where $N_2$ is sufficiently large:
$$A - \varepsilon < \frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(2)}} < A + \varepsilon$$
Since as $n \to \infty$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(2)}} - \frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}}\right) = 0$$

Now we'll have to prove $2$ cases separately:

**Case $1$:** $A = 1$

From our previous argument it follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(2)}} = \dots = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(n-1)}} = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(1)}} = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \forall i \in \{1,\dots, n\} \quad \sup {Ran}_{\theta} X_i = \inf {Ran}_{\theta} X_i$$

$$\Rightarrow \forall i \in \{1,\dots, n\}\quad Var(X_i) = 0$$

Which is a contradiction, becuase in this case we assumed that $Var(X_i) \ne 0$.

**Case $2$:** $A \in \Bbb{R}^+_0 \backslash \{1\}$

Again, we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(2)}} = \dots = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(n-1)}} = A$$

Which is this case means:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{A}\frac{X^{(3)}}{X^{(1)}} = \dots =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{A^n}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(1)}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(1)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}A^n\frac{X^{(2)}}{X^{(1)}} = \\ = 0, +\infty \text{ or does not exist (depending on the value of } A)$$

It can't be $0$, since then $$\Bbb{P}(X_n = 0) = 1 \rightarrow \forall i \in \{1\dots n\}\quad \Bbb{P}(X_i = 0) = 1 \rightarrow Var(X_i) = 0$$
Which is a contradiction again.

It can' be $+ \infty$ either, because that can only occur if
$X_n \ne 0$ and $X_{n-1} = 0$, but as we've already discussed,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(n-1)}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X^{(n-1)}}{X^{(n-2)}} (= + \infty)$$

Which also means that $X_{n-1} \ne 0$ and $X_{n-2} = 0$, and we get a contradiction from $X_{n-1} = 0$ and $X_{n-1} \ne 0$.

The only option in this case is for the limit not to exist, which isn't technically a contradiction, but it further proves our point.

**Result:**

Both cases lead to contradiction, which means that the given limit does not exist.

Comment: I still need a couple of minutes to work through your proof; Thank you so much for your answer already - I highly appreciate it

Comment: Just a little remark; If $\mathbb P (X \in (0,a])>0$ for any fixed $a$, then e.g. variance 0 is simply not possible and also there is no "smallest" value that $X$ can take but the minimum will just converge to zero, getting smaller and smaller

Comment: @Johannes That's true, I glossed over the fact that $\mathbb P (X \in (0,a])>0$, but the proof is still valid, since we're trying to contradict the fact that the variance is $0$.

Comment: I either did not properly understand your proof or it is wrong; Imagine I have a random variable $X$ with supp$(X)=(1,\infty)$  and $\mathbb P(X \in (1,a])>0$ for any fixed $a>1$ (so everything shifted up by one) Then obviously both, the smallest and the second smallest realization will converge to one and hence the ratio will also converge to 1; However, if I understood your proof correctly, I could also show with the same arguments that this does not hold;

Comment: The basic idea for it to work must be that the minimum converges to zero; If it converges to some fixed number $a$ with $a \neq 0$, then the ratio will indeed converge to 1...

Comment: I don't think your Case 1 argument works as it stands. You can conclude that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X^{(k)}}{X^{(1)}}=1$ for any fixed $k$. But that is not the same as $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X^{(n)}}{X^{(1)}}=1$ and I don't see how that follows.

Comment: Exactly...That is the flaw in it